# Why cant i use static_cast<const char**>(str) instead of (const char**)str?

Tags: c++, string, static-cast

I have an issue, it doesn't want to cast using **static_cast<>**. What can it be?

```
void myCompare(const void *str)
{
    const char *ca = *(static_cast<const char**>(str)); //error
    const char *a = *(const char **)str; //ok
}
```

Comment: You're trying to convert a "pointer to constant" to a "pointer to non-constant", which  `static_cast` does not allow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're casting away `const` on the second level, which `static_cast` is not allowed to do (in fact, no "C++" cast apart from `const_cast`):

```
          void    const*
   char const*         *
// ^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^
// pointee        cv-qualifiers
//                of pointee
```

Instead, write

```
const char *ca = *(static_cast<const char* const*>(str));
```

---

The `(char const**)` cast works here because it is equivalent to a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast` (as per [expr.cast]/(4.3)) - i.e. it was equivalent to

```
const char *ca = *(const_cast<const char**>(static_cast<const char* const*>(str)));
```

Comment: @Columbo: Can you please explain more, your explanation is little confusing

Comment: @anurag86 I adjusted it, better now?